# Не работает browser sync

Tags: javascript, gulp, browsersync

Здравствуйте. Не могу разобраться никак, что не так? Все запускается при сохранении пишет Reloading Browsers, но не обновляет!

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "app"
        }
    });
});


    gulp.task('watch',['browser-sync'] , function() {
 gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload#using-reload-as-a-command-line-application

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему. Я не делал html разметку, а просто писал в файле без разметки. А работает только с разметкой. Если кто-то знает почему так, то расскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы во второй снизу строчки указываете за какими файлами следить, что gulp и делаелает